# What does the 'timings' object in a .HAR file mean?

Tags: networking, browser, har

I'm facing a browser issue whereby certain functionality is throwing a network error. Looking into the .HAR file, I reviewed the 'timings' object as below:

```
"timings": {
  "blocked": 72.3479999966314,
  "dns": -1,
  "ssl": -1,
  "connect": -1,
  "send": 0.2789999999999999,
  "wait": 213.88000000044144,
  "receive": 3.196000005118549,
  "_blocked_queueing": 69.7329999966314
}
```

Please help me to understand what these variables mean:

```
  "dns": -1,
  "ssl": -1,
  "connect": -1,
```

Answer (score 1):

The timings section is described in the HAR specification:

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#timings

The -1 values for the DNS, SSL and Connect values indicates that either these steps did not occur (i.e. an existing connection was reused) or that the creator of the HAR file did not have access to that information